# How to select next rows from database in C#?

Tags: c#, oledb

Here is the Code, I have tried, but it's not working.

```cs
con.Open();
String sql = "SELECT * from bills order by sr_no OFFSET 10 ROWS ONLY ";
cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
while (dr1.Read() == true)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr1[0], dr1[3]);
}
con.Close();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write code for next & previous button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673329/how-to-write-code-for-next-previous-button)

Comment: I would *strongly* advise you to learn about databinding which has a much more efficient way to display data

Answer (score 1):

Use OFFSET and FETCH :

```
SELECT col1, col2, ...
FROM ...
WHERE ... 
ORDER BY -- this is a MUST there must be ORDER BY statement
-- the paging comes here
OFFSET     10 ROWS       -- skip 10 rows
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY; -- take 10 rows
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from bills order by sr_no OFFSET number_of_rows_u_want_to_skip ROWS FETCH NEXT number_of_rows_u_want_to_take  ROWS ONLY
```